# How do i enable remote jmx with port in zookeeper zkServer.cmd

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Here my `zkServer.cmd` file :

```
@echo off


setlocal
call "%~dp0zkEnv.cmd"

set ZOOMAIN=org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

echo on

call %JAVA% "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=%ZOO_LOG_DIR%" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=%ZOO_LOG4J_PROP%" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" %ZOOMAIN% "%ZOOCFG%" %*

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First obtain the hostname (or reachable IP eg. lan/public/NAT address):

```
hostname -i
# or find ip
ip a
```

next add following options to ZOOMAIN (assumed hostname my.remoteconsole.org and desired port 8989)

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8989
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=my.remoteconsole.org
```

More details about available options in [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @kwarunek

Answer (score 6):

The skServer.sh script will run the zkEnv.sh script which in-turn will look for a script **'../conf/zookeeper-env.sh'**

create a file on the **conf** folder called **zookeeper-env.sh**

Paste this into the file and restart Zookeeper:

```
JMXLOCALONLY=false
JMXDISABLE=false
JMXPORT=4048
JMXAUTH=false
JMXSSL=false
```

Comment: Just adding JMXPORT to zookeeper-env.sh is enough. Other are defaults in zkEnv.sh. However, if you want to enable authentication or ssl, then these must be set.

Answer (score 0):

ADD org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain in server-start.

The class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain will start a JMX manageable ZooKeeper server. This class registers the proper MBeans during initalization to support JMX monitoring and management of the instance.

Comment: This only enables jmx for local monitoring. The question is asked is regarding remote monitoring.

Comment: Expose an ingress/egress port, remote or local until you have access.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer by [Marcell du Plessis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8863433/marcell-du-plessis), if you are running zookeeper as a systemd service, then you can specify jmx port in the environment variable.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kakfa Zookeeper
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=users
ExecStart=/your-zookeeper-install-path/bin/zkServer.sh start
ExecStop=/your-zookeeper-install-path/bin/zkServer.sh stop
TimeoutStopSec=180
Restart=on-failure
Environment="JMX_PORT=9999"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=zookeeper.service
```