# How to enable JMX port for Zookeeper server

Tags: apache-zookeeper, jmx

I am using Zookeeper version 3.4.6. I am trying to enable JMX for the same. Following below Url. Below are the changes I did in my zkServer.sh file

[How do i enable remote jmx with port in zookeeper zkServer.cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457491/how-do-i-enable-remote-jmx-with-port-in-zookeeper-zkserver-cmd/53761625)

```
 ZOOMAIN="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2989 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=HDP.trinityiot.local org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain"
```

Zookeeper is starting but JMX port is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

We have to add the below line in zkEnv.sh file

```
ZOOMAIN="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2989 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxxxx org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a systemd service you can do it like this with Environment parameter:

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'zookeeper-server-start zookeeper.properties > /var/log/zookeeper.log 2>&1'
ExecStop=zookeeper-server-stop
Restart=on-abnormal
Environment="JMX_PORT=9998"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: If using Kafka, Confluent already provides systemd scripts for Kafka and Zookeeper